# c# Powershell. Configure runspace using RunspaceConfiguration.Create

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm trying to find out how the `RunspaceConfiguration.Create()` method call is used. I want to set the c# hosting up, in a manner that will enable any conceivable powershell script from executing from c# by ensuring all Cmdlets, Providers etc, are available. Looking at the powershell samples, sample 5, it's got the following.

```
RunspaceConfiguration config = RunspaceConfiguration.Create("SampleConsole.psc1", out warnings);
```

How does the .psc1 get created, or where is stored, retrieved from. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I had to do some *evil* hackery to get this to happen - you can read it in the comments, but basically PS can't do this currently.

```
var _currentRunspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(this);

/* XXX: We need to enable dot-sourcing - unfortunately there is no 
 * way in code to just enable it in our host, it always goes out to
 * the system-wide settings. So instead, we're installing our own
 * dummy Auth manager. And since PSh makes us reimplement a ton of
 * code to make a custom RunspaceConfiguration that can't even properly 
 * be done because we only have the public interface, I'm using 
 * Reflection to hack in the AuthManager into a private field. 
 * This will most likely come back to haunt me. */

var t = typeof(RunspaceConfiguration);
var f = t.GetField("_authorizationManager", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
f.SetValue(_currentRunspace.RunspaceConfiguration, new DummyAuthorizationManager());

_currentRunspace.Open();
return _currentRunspace;


public class DummyAuthorizationManager : AuthorizationManager
{
    const string constshellId = "Microsoft.PowerShell";
    public DummyAuthorizationManager() : this (constshellId) {}
    public DummyAuthorizationManager(string shellId) : base(shellId) {}

    protected override bool ShouldRun(CommandInfo commandInfo, CommandOrigin origin, PSHost host, out Exception reason)
    {
        // Looks good to me!
        reason = null;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers,. 
That fixed one problem I didn't even know about. Thanks. Bob.

Answer (score 2):

A `.psc1` file can be created with the `Export-Console` cmdlet. Typically you would set up a console environment with your desired snap-ins and then export its configuration.

`RunspaceConfiguration.Create` most likely supports either absolute or relative paths to such a file.